# Gradle does not execute subprojects

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module

Currently I'm trying to migrate my project to gradle from maven and to do so I'm creating a custom script which generates gradle build files from pom files taking into account all project specifics. 
Script generates "build-generated.gradle" file which is meant to be executed on configuration phase from build.gradle file.

```
//Text of common build.gradle:
println "Configuring ${project.name}"
apply from: 'build-generated.gradle'
```

The problem is that when I try to run "gradle build" the result is not what I'm expecting:
An initialization phase all subprojects are included and futhermore I can print names of all subprojects using

```
subprojects{
    println "I'm ${project.name}"
}
```

but at configuration and execution phase the subproject's build.gradle files are not executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was adding root project into include chain in settings.gradle